# Adding ascii-art to command prompt through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, terminal, ascii, command-prompt

I have some code that opens up command prompt, and requires a user to sign in through windows command prompt. I've gotten complaints about it being really ugly that they have to log in like that, so I thought I'd add some Ascii-art to the terminal so it gives something to look at (below). Any ideas how I would be able to format that in VBA to result in some nice art for the terminal?
`shellOUT = oShell.Run("cmd.exe /s /c echo Art Here  &  " & f & "  " & cf, vbNormalFocus, True)` it would need to go in between "Echo" and "&" where it says "Art Here"

```
       ____             
      / __ \ ___  _   __
     / / / // _ \| | / /
    / /_/ //  __/| |/ / 
   /_____/ \___/ |___/
```

Comment: So I continued looking into as after I posted this, and now I'm working with  First Line .&echo. Second Line, and so on so on, we'll see how that goes lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
Dim myArt As String

myArt = _
    "       ____             " & vbNewLine & _
    "      / __ \ ___  _   __" & vbNewLine & _
    "     / / / // _ \| | / /" & vbNewLine & _
    "    / /_/ //  __/| |/ / " & vbNewLine & _
    "   /_____/ \___/ |___/  " & vbNewLine & _
    "                        " & vbNewLine

shellOUT = oShell.Run("cmd.exe /s /c echo " & myArt & ..., vbNormalFocus, True)
```

Comment: Ahh that makes way more sense, I was tryind to edit it with command prompt code itself